# RedirectMatch 301 to same directory

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

This is my .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

RedirectMatch 301 ^/index\.php/(.*) /$1
```

**RedirectMatch 301 ^/town/(.*)$ /town/sport-teacher-$1**

The last rule in bold is my problem. I would redirect every town name to the sport-teacher-*town* url but it give me a redirection loop.

I tried a lot of combinaison to exclude sport-teacher, but nothing works.

Someone could help me please ?

Comment: Is `/town/sport-teacher` a real URL or are you trying to redirect a fake URL to another Fake URL?

Comment: Hi Jack, each url is really accessible and exist at this time. /town/sport-teacher-* is a route for the controller town and the action "paris" for example which would give /town/sport-teacher-paris